# How to sort or manually arrange Evolution Mail Account Names in Preferences?

Tags: evolution

Is there some way I can re-arrange the order of Mail Account Names in Evolution's Properties dialog?

I find it strange that this list shows entries in the order in which I add them, and there is no facility to change this order.

The column is not sortable, and there are no Move-Up/Down buttons.

Update: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 (2.6.32-25-generic)... Evolution 2.28.3

Comment: Please add the version of both OS and evolution as tags. That will help to recreate the issue. I am using Evolution 2.30.3 and it automatically sorts the mail accounts in alphabetical order

Comment: Interesting.. Thanks... I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 (2.6.32-25-generic)... Evolution 2.28.3 ... and my system reports as "Up to date" via the Update manager... Maybe I can try the maverick repository.... Present your suggestion as an answer, and I'lll accept it.

Comment: I look at the "Maverick repositories in Lucid" option... At this point of time isn't a viable opton because the differences are too great, here is a link to my question about it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11509/is-it-safe-to-change-my-lucid-sources-to-maverick-to-get-one-app-then-revert-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug filed in launchpad regarding this issue :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/649610

Comment: Okay, thanks...  My Lucid 10.04 won't even sort the list... and it seems that Maverick 10.10 can now sort alphabetically, but no individual "move Up/Down" (or Drag-n-Drop) yet...

Comment: @fred: Hope they will include this feature in next release. 
 you may click on 'This bug affects <n> people' on the above url to inform the developers that you are also facing this issue.

Answer (score 15):

This issue has been addressed and now you CAN re-order folders. To do so, go into Edit/Preferences/Mail Accounts. In that view you can drag folders to the order you desire, as well as select a default account.

I am using Evolution 3.10.4 in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm surprised this is not the accepted answer.

Comment: That's because my answer came years after the current accepted answer, but apparently the OP doesn't monitor this post any more, or doesn't care enough to change it.

Comment: I can confirm this works for me with Evolution 3.30.4 on Fedora 29. I tried dragging the emails in the main window, but it didn't have any effect. Doing it on the preferences works.

Comment: Agreed, the apparent up/down arrows that show up on the main screen are certainly misleading.

Comment: Only thing I can do is to upvote, since this answer is correct. The arrows are misleading, so I wouldn't even think to go to Preferences. Thank you @BobDoolittle

Answer (score 1):

I agree with aneeshep, under Ubuntu 10.10 they are sorted alphabetically.  If the order is not to your liking, prefix the account names with numbers is all I can suggest.

As far as I am aware there isn't a way to manually change the order, but I am quite happy to be corrected.

Maybe it is something that should be filed as a feature request to the evolution team.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll just have to wait until I make the shift to 10.10.. I'm in no hurry (I'm still learning to drive the "lucid" distro...  and not ready to ride a "maverick", yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently prefixing my accounts with numbers to achieve the order I want them displayed.  Hopefully the evolution team is working on adding the convenience of drag n drop hierarchy.